# build neo4j browser GET MojoExecutionException

Tags: neo4j

I am getting an error when I build neo4j.
I know it is in browser component and I do install node.js.
I tried it on both Windows and Ubuntu and got same error.
I know I can skip browser but I really want to build browser component.

Anyone have any idea about what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 06:11 min

[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-11T15:41:43-08:00

[INFO] Final Memory: 117M/677M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (default) on project neo4j-browser: An Ant BuildException has occured: unless=cmdsuccess -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

[ERROR]

[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :neo4j-browser
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to build Neo4j from source?

You have to install the correct version of node, npm, grunt and bower I think upfront.

See this section in the readme:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j#dependencies

Comment: I want to change the behavior of UI.  I do follow the instruction.  Maybe something wrong but I am not aware of.  Anyone have experience of trouble shoot this?